# Add a local attachment to New Message Form

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Web add-in which basically decrypts SMIME content and displays it to the user. To achieve this, I'm creating a new display form using displayNewMessageForm and populating it with content. This works fine for mail with not attachments. However for mail with attachments, I would like to know if there's a way to add the attachments that already resides on the local machine. Since the attachments itself are considered sensitive, I prefer not to upload it to any source.

So basically, my question is: anyway to populate a new message form using a local file path or extracting the actual binary data of the attachment instead?

Thanks!

I've already tried displayNewMessageForm, but it only accepts the URI to the attachment.

Comment: Currently this not a part of the displayNewMessageFormApi(). We track Outlook add-in feature requests on  [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins).Please add your request there.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Do you have any alternative I could explore in order to display attachments in a new message form? Would it be possible to re-create the form? Thanks!

Comment: Currently there is no support for the same, please update the request in the above mentioned link.